# Change data frame shape merging columns into one

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a data frame like this

```
TargetID       A    B  knowngene
cg00000108 0.8644845 0.9289447 uc003chb.3
cg00000108 0.8644845 0.9289447 uc003cha.4
cg00000109 0.8810606 0.9109397 uc003fhy.3
cg00000109 0.8810606 0.9109397 uc003fhz.4
cg00000109 0.8810606 0.9109397 uc003fia.3
```

the idea is to change this in order to get this new one

```
knowngene    Meth_info
uc003chb.3   cg00000108;0.8644845;0.9289447
uc003cha.4   cg00000108;0.8644845 0.9289447
uc003fhy.3   cg00000109;0.8810606;0.9109397
uc003fhz.4   cg00000109;0.8810606;0.9109397
uc003fia.3   cg00000109;0.8810606;0.9109397
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply try this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(knowngene, 
          Meth_info= paste(TargetID,";",A,";",B,sep="")
          ,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

using paste on vectors simply pastes the items line by line - soooo handy.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much lifted from `duplicated.data.frame`:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "TargetID       A    B  knowngene
cg00000108 0.8644845 0.9289447 uc003chb.3
cg00000108 0.8644845 0.9289447 uc003cha.4
cg00000109 0.8810606 0.9109397 uc003fhy.3
cg00000109 0.8810606 0.9109397 uc003fhz.4
cg00000109 0.8810606 0.9109397 uc003fia.3", header = TRUE)

# Paste together the first three columns
theStrings <- do.call(paste,c(dat[,-4],sep=";"))

# create a data.frame of the results
(dat2 <- data.frame(dat[,4, drop = FALSE], Meth_info = theStrings))

#    knowngene                     theStrings
# 1 uc003chb.3 cg00000108;0.8644845;0.9289447
# 2 uc003cha.4 cg00000108;0.8644845;0.9289447
# 3 uc003fhy.3 cg00000109;0.8810606;0.9109397
# 4 uc003fhz.4 cg00000109;0.8810606;0.9109397
# 5 uc003fia.3 cg00000109;0.8810606;0.9109397
```